# OOP, enforcing method call order

Tags: oop, design-patterns

#### Question:

This is a question about OOP practice. I've run into a situation while working with an API where there are a series of methods that need to be called in a specific order.

#### Case:

Controlling the operation of a smart sensor.

A simplified version of the interaction goes like this: first the API must be configured to interface with the sensor over TCP, the next command starts the scanning process, followed by receiving input for multiple items until the command to stop is given. At that time a similar series of disconnect commands must be given. If these are executed out of order an exception is thrown.

I see a conflict between the concepts of modularization and encapsulation here. Each of the steps is a discrete operation and thus should be encapsulated in separate methods, but they are also dependent on proper order of execution.

I'm thinking from the perspective of a later developer working on this code. It seems like someone would have to have a high level of understanding of this system before they could work on this code and that makes it feel fragile. I can add warning comments about this call order, but I'm hoping there's some principle or design pattern that might fit my situation.

Here's an example:

```
class RemoteTool
{
    public void Config();
    public void StartProcess();
    public void BeginListen();

    public void StopProcess();
    public void StopListening();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemoteTool MyRemoteTool = new RemoteTool();

        MyRemoteTool.Config();
        MyRemoteTool.StartProcess();
        MyRemoteTool.BeginListen();

        // Do some stuff

        MyRemoteTool.StopListening();
        MyRemoteTool.StopProcess();
    }
}
```

The closest thing I can think of is to use boolean flags and check them in in each function to assure that the prerequisite functions have already been called, but I guess I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: You should consider looking at [Continuation Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am struggling with the broadness of this question. If you have functions `A`, `B`, and `C`, and every time you call `C`, `A` and `B` must be called *immediately* beforehand, then you just wrap them in a function that calls `A` and `B` before `C`. If you can call `C` as long as at some point you called `A` and `B` (i.e. `A`, `B`, `C`, `C`, `C`, etc.), you just call `A` and `B` in your object constructor and add a `reconfigure` or `reboot` function to call them again. IMHO, this question does not have enough detail for a solid answer. So, **it depends**.

Comment: It might require a bit of refactoring, but one way of solving this might be to create a class for each state. (ie `tool.start_process()` returns a `Process` object which has a `.stop()` method - which presumably returns any data the `tool` needs).

Comment: Alternatively, if all the logic needs to stay in a single place, this could all be built on top of a [State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to the fact that the RemoteTool class has a [contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537018/what-does-contract-of-a-class-mean) that requires some pre-condition. e.g. : method b() has to execute() after method a().

If your language does not provide a mechanism to define these kinds of pre-conditions, you need to implement one yourself.

I agree with you that to implement this extra functionality (or these specific class contract features) 
inside RemoteTool() class could degrade your current design. A simple solution could be use another class with the responsibility of enforce the needed pre-condition before call the specific method of RemoteClass.(RemoteToolProxy() can be a suitable name)

This way you will decouple the concrete functionality and the contract that says how to use it.

There are other alternatives provided by a software design approach called [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) 
that can give you other ways of improving your class contract.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method I found while looking for an answer. It's pretty simple, it helps, but doesn't *solve* my issue.

Essentially the class is created exactly in the question, but the dependant functions are created as protected and a public member is created to keep them in order like so:

```
class RemoteTool
{
    public bool Running = false;
    public void Run()
    {
        Config();
        StartProcess();
        BeginListen();

        Running = true;
    }

    public void Stop() {
        StopListening();
        StopProcess();

        Running = false;
    }

    protected void Config();
    protected void StartProcess();
    protected void BeginListen();

    protected void StopProcess();
    protected void StopListening();
}
```

The trouble is that you still have to call Stop() and Run() in the right order, but they're easier to manage and the modularization is higher.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I have a similar problem. The solution that's most appealing to me so far is to have a class for each state, each with a factory method to get to the next state. So in your case you'd have three classes like:

```
class RemoteTool {
  public ConfiguredRemoteTool Configure();
}

class ConfiguredRemoteTool {
  public Listener StartProcess();
}

class Listener {
  public void BeginListen();
}
```

There are tradeoffs. This is arguably a "more confusing" API, if your metric for confusion is number of classes. However, it's much harder to use incorrectly, and with good naming and code organization, it could be easy to understand. If any part of the process gets more complicated, you can easily add methods to any of the classes without muddying up the others.

If you're using Java these could be inner classes so you're clearly communicating their relation to each other. In C++, you could put them in the same header file.

Comment: Oh man! This was a good thread. It's been a lot of years since then. I now know about State Machines and DAGs. I think those concepts would help solve this problem nicely. You should have a look! Thanks for bringing me back!