# is `contract of a class` only defined by public interface?

Tags: java

I was reading about 'contract of a class' on [Her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537018/what-does-contract-of-a-class-mean) and everyone seems to be indicating that it is only for `public` properties and methods. Is it the case?

I think the contract of a class is not limited to just the public interface but also the private methods and fields. So, It is most of the times, how a method is behaving - it's access modifier, return type and thrown exception - is under contract.

For example the following method:
`private String returnString()` is still under the contract that it will return a `String`.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It will only return a String inside of the class where that method is defined because it is private... A contract is more of what is visible/available to the outside world

Comment: The clients don't care (and should not) about private methods.

Comment: @RobOhRob isn't return type of methods and thrown exception come under contract? Like a class guarantees that the method will only return a String type and will only throw some Exception. isn't it a contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private` methods aren't exposed, and as such, can't be part of any *`public`* contract.

A class which adheres to a contract (e.g. through an interface) guarantees that it will expose certain `public` methods, and sometimes, fields, to a downstream consumer.  How it goes about fulfilling that contract is an implementation detail, often times executed through private methods.

Comment: isn't return type of methods and thrown exception come under contract? Like a class guarantees that the method will only return a `String` type and will only throw `some Exception`. isn't it a contract?

Comment: One could add that in addition to the signature of the method (checked by the compiler), additionally certain pre-, post conditions and invariants have to hold (documented in the java doc/specification and enforced by the programmer of the implementation). E.g. that a `List<T> sort(List<T> items)` method will return not only a `List<T>`, but that list will also be sorted.

Comment: @lynxx:  A return type isn't part of a method's formal signature.  Besides, you're still referring to private methods. Here's an analogy - suppose you went out to lunch with friends and you wanted to pay your portion.  The *public* facing part of this contract is that you will pay.  *How* you pay is an implementation detail; you could pull out cash or a card or PayPal it to someone else at the table.  In public, you're paying for your meal.  In private, you're determining where the funds come from.  The contract of paying for your meal isn't broken if you use cash *instead* of card or PayPal.

Comment: @Makoto I am not talking in the case of private methods. For this method, `public String getName()` We can a guarantee that the return type will be `String`.  Can I say that the method is under a contract that it will only return `String`? So here, are the terms `guarantee` and `contract` different in this context?

Comment: @lynxx:  Not...necessarily.  Not unless that was actually enforceable at compile time (e.g. through an interface or abstract class), since [**the return type of a method is *not* part of the method signature**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16149285/1079354).  You could claim that there's an implied contract that `getName` will return `String`, but few people do this; it's more about what `getName` will actually return.  Does it return the first name?  First and last?  Full name?  *Those* are more pertinent contract details.