# How to deal with base class methods that are incompatible with the derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Imagine that you're making a GUI and have a `DataViewList` class that is a widget that displays rows of data ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV7Oi.png) for example). You have methods `AddRow(std::vector<std::string> row)`, `DeleteRow(std::vector<std::string> row)` and `AddColumn(std::string name)`, `DeleteColumn(std::string name)`.

Now lets say you want to make a new class that displays a music playlist. It has predetermined columns (Title, Album, Year) and you don't want to ever add any new columns or delete existing ones. Also you want to be able to add `Song` objects to the list in a single method call, so you need a method that can do that. How do you implement such a class?

The most basic idea is to just create a new class `MusicPlaylsit` that inherits publicly form `DataViewList` and add the predetermined columns in the constructor. Then overload the `AddRow` methods such that it accepts `Song` objects as an argument. This approach has a big problem: Someone could call `MusicPlaylist::AddColumn` or other methods that are incompatible with the logic of the `MusicPlaylist` class. Since MusicPlaylist should only ever have the three predefined columns, then there shouldn't be a way to add or delete columns (or access any other incompatible base class methods such as the base class non-overloaded AddRow method).

To solve this, I can use composition instead of inheritance and re-implement any methods that I may want to use. In my opinion this is a bad idea because if I want to change something in the future, it's more difficult than inheritance because I cant override the base class methods.

Another option is to inherit as `protected`. This prevents using incompatible base class methods AND allows for overriding in case of future inheritance. The problem is, now I have to explicitly declare every method I want to use as public with `using`, which seems to be against the whole point of object oriented programming (being able to change something in a deep base class and still have any inherited class be able to use it) because newly added public methods in `DataViewList` will not be visible in `MusicPlaylist` or any classes that inherit from it until they have been explicitly made public.

So my question is: which pattern should I use when creating a new class that has an "is a" relationship to a base class, but is only partially compatible with it's methods?

Thanks

Comment: Inheritance represents the relationship "A fullfills the contract of B". If your `DataViewList` represents editable columns and your `MusicPlaylist` is not editable, then `MusicPlaylist` does not fullfill the contract of `DataViewList` and must not inherit it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the contract of B"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537018/what-does-contract-of-a-class-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step back and look at your design again:

```
class DataViewList {
    using Col = std::string;
    using Row = std::vector<std::string>;
    virtual void addRow(Row) = 0;
    virtual void deleteRow(Row) = 0;
    virtual void addColumn(Col) = 0;
    virtual void deleteColumn(Col) = 0;
    virtual void draw(Context) = 0;   // not in your question, but inferred
};
```

What you want to do is:

```
class MusicPlaylist : public DataViewList { /* ... */ }
```

And you discovered this cannot work, because `MusicPlaylist` does not fulfill the contract defined by `DataViewList`. Let's review this. What are the responsibilities of `DataViewList`?

- It draws.
- It provides a list of items.
- It modifies that list of items.

That's 3 responsibilities. That violates 2 of the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID):

- A class must have only one responsibility (Single-responsibility).
- Consumer must not be forced to depend on things they do not use (Interface segregation).

And this is why you have a problem: `MusicPlaylist` only cares about 2 of those responsibilities, drawing and maintaining a list of items. It **does not** maintain a list of fields, and thus cannot inherit `DataViewList`.

**How to fix?**

Split the responsibilities.

```
// An interface for a data grid. Only provides a read-only view. No drawing.
struct DataList {
    virtual const std::vector<Column>& getColumns() const = 0;
    virtual const std::vector<Row>& getRows() const = 0;
protected:
    ~DataList(); // or make it public virtual to be able to delete a DataList*
};

// The widget that draws data.
class DataViewList : public Widget {
public:
    virtual void setData(const DataList&); //could be a pointer, YMMV
    virtual void draw(Context);
};
```

Note how:

- `DataViewList` no longer contains any data, instead it will reference some other object that contains the data.
- As it only shows the data, it depends on a simple interface that only contains reading functionnality.

At this point you can simply make a:

```
// Contains music data - does not draw it
class MusicPlaylist : public DataList {
    void addSong(Song);
    void deleteSong(Song);
    const std::vector<Column>& getColumns() const override;
    const std::vector<Row>& getRows() const override;
};

// Contains more complex data with configurable columns - does not draw it
class SomeMoreComplexList : public DataList {
    void addColumn(Col);
    void deleteColumn(Col);
    void addRow(Row);
    void deleteRow(Row);
    const std::vector<Column>& getColumns() const override;
    const std::vector<Row>& getRows() const override;
};
```

That is, your lists implement the interface that the widget requires to be able to display them, plus whatever specific functionality they need. You can then give them to the widget's `setData`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "partially is-a" relationship. Either `MusicPlaylist` can do everything a `DataViewList` advertises, or `MusicPlaylist` is not a `DataViewList`.

`DataViewList` advertises to be able to `AddColumn`. Perhaps it is too optimistic a promise. Most kinds of data only have fixed sets of columns that make sense, so perhaps `AddColumn` should be moved to a separate subclass of `DataViewList`. Say, `EditableColumnsDataViewList`?

On the other hand, perhaps it is not such a big deal to allow users to add columns to any kind of data. Maybe *you* think that columns like `colour` or `shape` or `distanceFromParis` don't make much sense for a song, but what if your users have different ideas?